# Why I can't find or enter entry in tkinter that was added to file?

Tags: python, file, tkinter

```
with open("emails.txt", "a+") as emailList:
    for line in emailList:
        if str(emailEntry.get()) in line:
            print("Someone already used this e-mail")
            break;
        else:
            emailList.write("\n" + str(emailEntry.get()))
```

#This chunk of code should check if in emails.txt is same string as entered with Entry widget in tkinter, if there is same string as entered program needs to print "Someone already used this e-mail" and stop that if statement. If in emails.txt is not same string as entered it should add that string to file.
#But my program is everytime (whatever I enter) not doing anything

Comment: What do you mean by "can't find"? Does the code you posted throw errors? If so, what are the errors? Please create a complete [mcve].

Comment: Sorry I am new here, I changed it now. Thank you for instructions.

Comment: You need to provide a _complete_ but minimal example. Maybe you're calling this code at the wrong time. Maybe you have two variables named `emailEntry`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you open the file in `a+` mode, which put the file pointer at the end of the file. Therefore the for loop will end immediately and nothing happens.

You need to open the file in `r+` mode.  Below is a working example:

```
email = emailEntry.get().strip()
if email:
    with open('emails.txt', 'r+') as emailList:
        found = False
        for line in emailList:
            if email == line.strip():
                found = True
                break
        if found:
            print('Someone already used this e-mail')
        else:
            print('add', email, 'to file')
            emailList.write('\n'+email)
```